# How to mix a list and regular params in same query using Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters, dapper

Given the following SQL statement for MySQL

```
var sql = @"INSERT INTO MyTable (Key1, Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES (@key, @field1, @field2, @field3)
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE Field3 = @existing";
```

I would normally build up the values list like this *(highly modified for this demo)*:

```
var values = new List<Object> {
 { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx" },
 { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx" },
 { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx" },
};
```

Then I would execute this simply by using:

```
await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, values);
```

But now, I need this extra "**ON DUPLICATE**" statement in the same SQL statement.  How do I put the params object together to handle the "@existing" parameter as well?

Comment: try to add an additional object to the list with parameter "existing" to match the parameter name "@existing" in SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `existing` parameter to each anonymous object in your collection of parameters values that you're passing to `ExecuteAsync`.

For example, this ends up inserting just one row in the database and `Field3` has the value `"three"`:

```cs
var values = new List<Object> {
 new { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx", existing = "one" },
 new { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx", existing = "two" },
 new { key = "xxx", field1 = "xxx", field2 = "xxx", field3 = "xxx", existing = "three" },
};

await connection.ExecuteAsync("""
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Key1, Field1, Field2, Field3)
    VALUES (@key, @field1, @field2, @field3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Field3 = @existing
    """, values);
```

(If you want the same `@existing` value for each row that is inserted, you would set `existing =` to the same value in each anonymous object, instead of making them different, as I did in this example.)